# Where are Iterator interface methods hasNext(), next(), remove() defined? Because interfaces never define methods only declare

Tags: java, interface, iterator, polymorphism

Where are Iterator interface method like hasNext(), next(), remove(), etc defined? Interfaces don't define methods, only declare methods that are defined in other classes. How can we directly access hasnext(), next(), etc methods through Iterator reference?
For example:

```
List l = new LinkedList();
l.add(1);
l.add(2); 
Iterator iter = l.iterator();
while(iter.hasNext())
{
    Object o = iter.next();
    System.out.println(o);
}
```

In the above example using reference iter (Iterator reference) can we assign any method in iter reference? Please give me an example with code. I could not understand this concept until now.

Comment: Edited for spelling/grammar/syntax/indentation.

Answer (score 4):

If your question is: where is the implementation of the LinkedList iterator, the answer is:
 it's implemented as a private inner class of the LinkedList class:

```
private class ListItr implements ListIterator<E> {
    private Node<E> lastReturned = null;
    private Node<E> next;
    private int nextIndex;
    private int expectedModCount = modCount;

    ...
}
```

Comment: To be clear, these details are deliberately hidden from you so you don't have to worry about them, and so that the Java implementors can swap in a different implementation later without breaking any users.

Answer (score 2):

You know you can find the answer yourself by either looking at the java source code, which can be downloaded, or you can print out the class of the iterator you get back here.

But more generally, the point of this is abstraction. The designer here designed specifically so you don't have to worry about these details