# What is iterator in java actually?

Tags: java, iterator

I have searched in JavaDoc, Iterator in java is interface. But if it is interface then where is the implementation of the **hasNext**, **next** , **remove** methods of iterator interface.

I tried to search in Stackoverflow for this question and i come up with this thread.

[Where are Iterator interface methods hasNext(), next(), remove() defined? Because interfaces never define methods only declare](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11350035/where-are-iterator-interface-methods-hasnext-next-remove-defined-becaus)

As mentioned in above thread its implementation is hidden But why it is hidden ?

Comment: It sounds like your question really isn't about iterators specifically, but interfaces in general - it's up to the class that implements the interface to provide the implementation...

Comment: In the link you have given, there is a reason also specifying why it is hidden...

Comment: Yes, So if i use arrayList class of collection framework then it doesn't have any implementation of these methods. Thats why i asked this question. @JonSkeet

Comment: `ArrayList` doesn't implement `Iterator` though - it implements `Iterable`, and when you call `iterator()` it returns an instance of an implementation of `Iterator`.

Comment: I know. See code down sent by hyperion. It is implemented by inner class of java's ArrayList. @JonSkeet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand you implement these method for your data structured to comply with the interface. There are no implementations available for the `hasNext()`, `next()` and `remove()` method as such.

Concrete classes have an implementation of these (default implementation). Like `LinkedList` traverses in order. For iterating in any other order you can implement the interface. Below is an example to iterate in reverse order:

```
@Override
public Iterator<Type> iterator() {
    Iterator<Type> it = new Iterator<Type>() {

        private int currentIndex = arrayList.size();

        @Override
        public boolean hasNext() {
            return arrayList[currentIndex] != null;
        }

        @Override
        public Type next() {
            return arrayList[currentIndex--];
        }

        @Override
        public void remove() {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
        }
    };
    return it;
}
```

Comment: Then how does it check for the next object and remove them in collection without any implementation ?

Comment: Each individual/concrete implementation has there own check in place.

Comment: hasNext could be more simple return currentIndex != 0;

Answer (score 1):

That is the idea of interface. Generally in programming the weaker connection you have between objects the better. Only interface is exposed intentionally for collections. It is expected from client to NOT TO KNOW ( or better there is no reason to know ) how implementation of iterator looks like, client expect described behaviour from iterator - check if has next element, get next element. How it is implemented is irrelevant and only that matters to him. The point is that you want use it and you only should know concept of iterator itself.

This is reason why is hidden

Answer (score 1):

Interfaces just blueprints. They told just WHAT to do, not HOW. Classes which implements X interface (eg. Iterator) MUST told HOW to do. If you look ArrayList's source code, you'll see implementation of Iterator's methods, like [image: ArrayList.java]

Comment: Got it, +1 to your answer. I wonder why community member have marked -1 to the question.

Comment: @Avin: Probably because your question purports to be able to a single interface, but is really about interfaces in general - and could probably have been self-answered with a bit more research. The downvote wasn't mine, but I can understand it.

Comment: Why post this as a screenshot rather than as text?